# Internet sharing not working over a one hop LAN

Tags: linux, networking, internet

I have a broadband ADSL connection to a modem router. I have connected this router 'A' to another wifi-modem router 'B' through a LAN cord.

Internet works fine in windows with wifi connection.

However, in linux (Android, Fedora, Ubuntu) it connects to the wifi network but I am not able to use internet.

Please note that all settings are automatic DHCP.

Comment: How are the two routers connected? LAN-to-LAN or LAN-to-WAN? Are both routers acting as DHCP servers or just one? Can the Linux machine reach either or both routers? If so, which?

Comment: There's a lot to be said for buying a combined ADSL-Modem/Router/Firewall/4-port-switch/Wifi-access-point all in one box that more-or-less just works as soon as you plug it in. In fact they seem to be predominant in this part of the world.

Comment: Being unfamiliar with Linux these suggestions will be somewhat vague, but...Can you ping 4.2.2.2? what is the result of a traceroute to 4.2.2.2? and what's in the routing table on the systems that aren't connecting?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Resolved. Both are acting as DHCP servers. I disabled the DHCP of router B and all started working perfectly. Thank you for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being faced was that both the routers were acting as DHCP servers assigning the same range of IP addresses.

I switched off DHCP server from Router B and everything worked fine.